# C++ - Linux - Delete Files In A Specified Directory That Are At Least 5 Days Old

Tags: c++, linux

How would I modify this code to delete all files in a specified directory that are at least 7 days old.  Here is the following source code I have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <direct.h>
#include <cstring>

int main(int argc, char* argv[1]) { 
 if (argc < 2) { 
      std:cerr<<"Usage: " << argv[0] << " <filename>" << std::endl;
      return 1;
 }

 struct stat buffer;

 for (int i; i < argc; ++i) { 
      int result = stat(argc[i], &buffer);

      if (result != 0) { 
           std::cerr << argv[i] << ": "<<stderror(errno) << std::endl;
           continue;
      }

      char datetime[100] = [0];
      const struct tm* time = localtime(sbuffer.st_mtime);
      result = strftime(datetime, 100, "%c", time);

      std::cout << argv[i] << ": " << datetime << std::endl;
 }

 return 0;
}
```

How would I get this to get the age of the file and delete files older than 7 days old?  Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read *carefully* the [stat(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) and [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html) man pages. Your `sbuffer` contains a `st_mtime` field. Compare it to the current time, obtained e.g. using [time(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/time.2.html)

Notice that a day is usually 86400 seconds, so 7 days is 7*86400 i.e. 604800 seconds.

To delete a file, use [unlink(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/unlink.2.html). I woud recommend using [readdir(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html) with [opendir(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/opendir.3.html) to read the directory. (But ignore the `..` and `.` entries).

I would also recommend collecting the list of file names to be removed, e.g. in a `std::vector<std::string>`

If you want to recursively scan directories (and their subdirectories, etc), consider [nftw(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/nftw.3.html)

(You probably don't want to use `system` in your home work)

Answer (score 2):

It can be as simple as:

```
system( "find <dir> -maxdepth 1 -mtime 5 -exec rm -f {} \;" );
```

But if you have specific requirements you need to post them.

Comment: I'm not sure this is a valid answer for such a homework.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch why did I put disclaimer for requirements?

Comment: @asveikau OP's question - C++ on Linux.

Comment: @Slava - The fact that they are on C++ on Linux doesn't make `system()` any less of a bad idea.